# Showing that $\sum{x^k}$ does not converge uniformly on $(-1,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

I a question about showing that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty{x^k}$ does not converge uniformly on $(-1,1)$. My professor gave a proof which starts as follows:

Let $s(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}$ and $s_n(x) = \frac{x-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ and consider the tail end $r_n(x) = s(x) - s_n(x) = \frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}$. He then says (and this is where my question is) that if we show that $r_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly to $0$ on $(-1,1)$ then our sum does not converge uniformly.

My question is: do we say that "then the sum does not converge uniformly" because the point-wise limit is $0$, or is there a property about the tail end of the series that I am  missing?

Comment: That $s_n$ converges uniformly would exactly mean that $s(x)-s_n(x) \to 0$, uniformly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)$ converges uniformly over some interval $(a,b)$ to $f(x)$  if and only if the sequence of the partial sums $S_N(x)=\sum_{k=1}^Nf_k(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$, i.e., if and only if $S_N(x)-f(x)$ converges uniformly to zero.